# Hide a tr only if td contains no content AFTER a specific html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to examine the content within a tr, AFTER an html element (br) to see if any exists? If there is no content after the br element, I'd like to hide the parent td. Please note that the html code is system generated and I cannot edit it.

I'm just not sure where to begin with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
    <table class="tabledefault">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="customfields">
                <table class="tabledefault">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><!-- this TR should be hidden -->
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451068"><strong>Laser Tag</strong>
                            <br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451069"><strong>Arcade</strong>
                            <br>Selected
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_450908"><strong>Bounce House (45 minutes) $100</strong>
                            <br>False
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451307"><strong>Party Room Rental (per hour) $75</strong>
                            <br>True</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I meant to say that I'd like to hide the parent tr (not td) if there is no content after the br within the td.

Comment: You should edit your question (the edit button is in the bottom left corner)

Comment: It would be much simpler if you wrapped the content in its own element instead of trying to detect text after the br.

Comment: Can you generate like <tr> <td> <strong>xxx<strong><br><span class="sub-content">true</span></strong></td></tr> ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.each()` , `nextSibling` , `nodeValue` , `String.prototype.match()` , `.closest()`

```js
$("table tr td br").each(function(i, el) {
  // if `br` next sibling does not contain alphanumeric characters,
  // hide parent `tr` element
  if (el.nextSibling.nodeType === 3 
      && el.nextSibling.nodeValue.match(/\w+/) === null
      || $(el).next(":empty").length) {
    $(this).closest("tr").hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table class="tabledefault">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="customfields">
                <table class="tabledefault">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><!-- this TR should be hidden -->
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451068"><strong>Laser Tag</strong>
                            <br><span></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451069"><strong>Arcade</strong>
                            <br>Selected
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_450908"><strong>Bounce House (45 minutes) $100</strong>
                            <br>False
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="CAT_Custom_451307"><strong>Party Room Rental (per hour) $75</strong>
                            <br>True</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Nice one. I was allowing for multiple `br` elements, but it's true there aren't any in the HTML in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"I was allowing for multiple br elements, but it's true there aren't any in the HTML in the question. "_ Appear to be multiple `br` elements at `html` at Question ? Substituted `.each()` for `.map()` ; see updated post.

Comment: I meant per row. Also, what if there's an element after the `br`, not just text?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"Also, what if there's an element after the br, not just text? "_ not entire clear from Question for case where element exists after `br` , though no content inside of element ; used `.next()` , `:empty` , though could probably use `.nextAll()` . See updated post

Comment: Indeed, like multiple `br` in the same `tr`, it's me coding defensively. :-) (That's my +1, btw)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"it's me coding defensively. :-)"_ Yes, likewise ; also "content" at  _"If there is no content after the br element"_ is not clearly defined

Comment: You guys are awesome! How would I go about binding this to an ajax load? http://crownsportscenter.mattswinehart.com/parties       Also - I apologize for any vagueness. I'd hoped to have more time to research things but a family illness has slowed my progress.

Comment: @MattSwinehart _"How would I go about binding this to an ajax load?"_ Try adding `js` at post to `success` function of `$.ajax()` , after any content has been appended to document .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just get the `tr`s, then find out if the first `<br>` element inside the first `<td>` has any following element siblings (I'm making an assumption there, that you don't want those hidden), or any following text node siblings that aren't blank. jQuery's `contents` is handy for that, as it includes text nodes. I'd probably loop through them backward:

```
$("#customfields .tabledefault tr").each(function(index) {
  var $tr = $(this);
  $tr.find("td:first").contents().get().reverse().some(function(node) {
    if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "BR") {
      // Hide it, and we're done looping
      $tr.hide();
      return true;
    }
    if (node.nodeType != 3 || $.trim(node.nodeValue)) {
      // Don't hide it, and we're done looping
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

I expect that can be optimized, but you get the idea.

**Live Example:**

```js
var counter = 3;
tick();

function tick() {
  $("#countdown").text(counter--);
  if (counter < 0) {
    hideIt();
  } else {
    setTimeout(tick, 500);
  }
}

function hideIt() {
  $("#customfields .tabledefault tr").each(function(index) {
    var $tr = $(this);
    $tr.find("td:first").contents().get().reverse().some(function(node) {
      if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "BR") {
        // Hide it, and we're done looping
        $tr.hide();
        return true;
      }
      if (node.nodeType != 3 || $.trim(node.nodeValue)) {
        // Don't hide it, and we're done looping
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<table class="tabledefault">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="customfields">
        <table class="tabledefault">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- this TR should be hidden -->
              <td id="CAT_Custom_451068"><strong>Laser Tag</strong>
                <br>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="CAT_Custom_451069"><strong>Arcade</strong>
                <br>Selected
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="CAT_Custom_450908"><strong>Bounce House (45 minutes) $100</strong>
                <br>False
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="CAT_Custom_451307"><strong>Party Room Rental (per hour) $75</strong>
                <br>True</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown">&nbsp;</div>
```